# js map why is not changing my value with return

Tags: javascript

I'm doing map with a variable, and doing a return to change his value, but it's not working, the value for the whole array is the same:

```
  //resultValues = processValues(table,resultValues,'toClient');
  resultValues.map ( (record) => {
    record = processValues(table,record,'toClient');
    return record;
  });
  return Promise.resolve(resultValues);  // does  not change
```

so I had to create another variable to be able to have a change on the array. why is this behavoiur? it's normal in map ?; is there another option with lodash by example to don't need create a second variable?

```
  let newResult = [];
  resultValues.map ( (record) => {
    record = processValues(table,record,'toClient');
    newResult.push(record);   // with this changes are sent to new var
    //return record;
  });
  // return Promise.resolve(resultValues);
  return Promise.resolve(newResult);
```

Comment: Did you read any documentation / tutorial / guide on `map`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array.map` returns a new array instance where each element inside it is transformed:

```js
let ret = resultValues.map (record => processValues(table,record,'toClient'));
return Promise.resolve(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

Map returns a new array. You could literally do:

```
const newArr = resultValues.map ( (record) => {
  record = processValues(table,record,'toClient');
  return record;
});
```

Please read the first sentence of the [MDN web docs for map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).